# vertex jumping to some point in edit mode

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

So I just started learning blender from the Blender guru: Blender Beginner Tutorial Series. I am at part 4 where he wants to edit the icing of the donut. I wanted to try to move it too with pressing
g-key and then z-key, it doesn't really goes well as you can see on the screenshots I took. I just goes from the one point directly to a sharp point in my icing and I don't know why. Did I do something with a shortcut? Or something in my settings? Can someone help me?

[image: doughnut and icing] "icing"

[image: icing with one vertex moved] "icing going wrong"

Comment: It looks all well for me. You have moved a vertex along the z axis.

Comment: You are probably missing a *Subsurf* modifier on your object

Comment: I don't want it to move so far. But it moves automatically moves there even if I dont want it to move as far. Here a short video with what happens 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xlQBvTPZEFQ

Comment: video of what went : wrong : youtube.com/watch?v=xlQBvTPZEFQ
GIF of what I want : https://makeagif.com/gif/blender-beginner-tutorial-part-4-material-nodes-JzsepG

Comment: @MrZak Thnx a lot that was the thing that was wrong really thnx a lot. I was  really frustrated ^^